# Not getting record from database sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I do not know where could i made a mistake, but here is a summary what i have done(I'm storing in database days of week which are chosen from calendar and i'm also storing the date from calendar, so i can later fetch data from database under selected date)

```
mWeekCalendar.setOnDateClickListener(new OnDateClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateClick(DateTime dateTime) {
            // Set text for selected date
            tvDateTime.setText(dateTime.toString(dtf));

            // No record exists under selected date, so we will create a new one
            if (!mDatabase.exists(dateTime.toString(formatter))) {
                Day day = new Day();
                day.setTitle(dateTime.toString(dtfDayInWeek));
                day.setDate(dateTime.toString(formatter));
                mDatabase.createDay(day);
            }

            // Util.showToastMessage(HomeActivity.this, dateTime.toString(formatter);
            // This is working fine and it shows toast message with date

            // Getting a day under selected date
            Day day = mDatabase.getDayByDate(dateTime.toString(formatter));
            Util.showToastMessage(HomeActivity.this, day.getDate());
            // This one shows empty toast message or any other getter i would try here
            // from Day class

        }
    });
```

Method for checking database if there is any record by selected date is working and insert method too, and i can see in database under column `day_date` the value i have passed from calendar `dateTime.toString(formatter)`. This is how my method for fetching data from database looks:

```
/**
 * Getting day under date
 */
public Day getDayByDate(String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DAYS + " WHERE "
            + KEY_DAY_DATE + " = " + date;


    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    Day day = null;

    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        day.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
        day.setTitle((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DAY_NAME))));
        day.setDate((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DAY_DATE))));
        day.setCreated_at(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
    } else {
        day = new Day();
    }

    return day;
}
```

This method retrieve record if record exists under selected date:

```
public boolean exists(String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select 1 from " + TABLE_DAYS + " where " + KEY_DAY_DATE + " =?",
            new String[] { date });
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: what values are in `KEY_DAY_DATE` and `date`? because if `date` is a date string, e.g. `2016-06-09`, then you're not doing date comparisons, you're doing arithemetic: `where foo = 2016-06-09` is actually `foo = 2016 minus 6 mins 9` and ends up being `foo = 1999`

Comment: Column `KEY_DAY_DATE` is text and before i'm storing date in db, i'm converting that date in string.

Comment: doesn't matter. you're doing `where sometext = 2016-06-09`. you're not comparing a value against a field. you're comparing two values against each other. and since the values aren't equal, you're effectively doing `where false`, which means NO records match.

Comment: @MarcB Your logic is good. Your math isn't: `2016 - 6 - 9` makes `foo = 2001`... ;)

Comment: doh. right... was doing `2016-(6+9)` in my head,

Comment: Okay @MarcB what is your suggestion? How should i retrieve data from database by selected date if not like this?

Comment: @MarcB i have updated my question. Why then my method `exists()` works and the logic is almost similar?

Comment: because there you're binding a parameter, which lets the DB see the date string in its entirety. it's the difference between handing over a bunch of parts and a fully assembled product. when you directly stuff `2016-06-09` into the query, the DB has ABSOLUTELY NO WAY of knowing that's a date, it just sees some subtraction operations. when you do the parameter, it sees a STRING enter the db, and the '2016-06-9'` stays as it is, a single entity representing a date string.

Comment: @MarcB Well, I dunno how to tell you: `2016-(6+9)` is still `2001`... XD

Comment: @BobMalooga: well, yeah. obviously I need a vacation or something. sad... I just got back from one last month.

Comment: @MarcB Should i bind then a parameter too in method where i'm retrieving records from DB?